# generate triangular matrix for square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that for any square matrix A there exist an invertible matrix B so that

$ BA=C $

where C is a triangular matrix.

Comment: Do you know about Gaussian elimination/row reduction?

Comment: @Castell, Yes I know about it.

Comment: Well, that's your answer! $C$ is the row reduced part, $B$ a product of elementary matrices corresponding to the row reduction steps.

Comment: But if A is not invertiable? it cannot be reduced , isn't it?

Comment: It can be reduced to a triangular matrix with some diagonal entries equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use $QR$ decomposition.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition

You could use Gaussian elimination, which is effectively the same as the $LU$ decomposition.  But I think most accounts assume that the matrix $A$ is invertible.  As the commentator said, you can get around this.  But you will probably need to go through the proof carefully to make sure it works.  So why not quote $QR$ when the work is done for you.